# Deserialize Json string to C# model

Tags: c#, json, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following JSON object which i get to my Web API controller:

```
{
    "id": "13",
    "title": "party",
    "periods": {
        "0": {
            "label": "Period",
            "start_date": "2015-04-20",
            "end_date": "2015-04-29"
        }
    }
}
```

I want to try to Deserialize this straight into a Model that i have in C# but I'm not able too.

Here is my Model:

```
    public class PeriodsModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("title")]
        public string title { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("periods")]
        public Periods periods { get; set; }
    }
    public class Periods
    {
        [JsonProperty("0")]
        public Dictionary<string,Period> period { get; set; }
    }

    public class Period
    {
        [JsonProperty("label")]
        public string label { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("start_date")]
        public string start_date { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("end_date")]
        public string end_date { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is my method in my controller:

```
public void Put([FromBody]JToken jsonbody)
{
    var myJsonObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonbody);
    PeriodsModel model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PeriodsModel>(myJsonObject);
}
```

Here is my error msg that i get:

```
An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error converting value "Period" to type 'CMS.WebApi.Controllers.ActivitiesController+Period'. Path 'periods.0.label', line 1, position 62.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the error message is correct. Drill down into the data a little... You have:

```
    "0": {
        "label": "Period",
        "start_date": "2015-04-20",
        "end_date": "2015-04-29"
    }
```

And you try to put it into:

```
public class Periods
{
    [JsonProperty("0")]
    public Dictionary<string,Period> period { get; set; }
}

public class Period
{
    [JsonProperty("label")]
    public string label { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("start_date")]
    public string start_date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("end_date")]
    public string end_date { get; set; }
}
```

---

So more specifically, this JSON:

```
    {
        "label": "Period",
        "start_date": "2015-04-20",
        "end_date": "2015-04-29"
    }
```

Is being deserialized to a `Dictionary<string,Period>`

---

So then the first property:

```
        "label": "Period"
```

Needs to be deserialized to a `<string, Period>` pair.
The left side `"label"` is properly converted to a `string` but the right side is a string `"Period"`, and that string can not be deserialized into the class type `Period`

Hence the error

> Error converting value "Period" to type 'CMS.WebApi.Controllers.ActivitiesController+Period'

It is trying to convert the string "Period" to the class Period.

---

It isn't totally clear what you want to do here, but if there is only ever a `"0"` in `periods` then you could just change the property to:

```
public class Periods
{
    [JsonProperty("0")]
    public Period period { get; set; }
}
```

But my guess is that you would want to have more than 1 period, so you would have "0", "1", "2" ... etc.

Without putting together some code to test it, I'm not sure if there is a good way to do that.

You might want to try making the `PeriodsModel` have:

```
    [JsonProperty("periods")]
    public Dictionary<string, Period> periods { get; set; }
```

and then you wouldn't need a `Periods` class at all.

Though usually when I have a variable number of things to pass, I just use a JSON array instead, like:

```
{
    "id": "13",
    "title": "party",
    "periods": [
        {
            "label": "Period1",
            "start_date": "2015-04-20",
            "end_date": "2015-04-29"
        }, {
            "label": "Period2",
            "start_date": "2015-04-20",
            "end_date": "2015-04-29"
        }, {
            "label": "Period3",
            "start_date": "2015-04-20",
            "end_date": "2015-04-29"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, I would also like to have an array of objects instead. But I have nothing to do how the Json is formated in the frontend, im only suppose to handle it on server side hence my problem.

Comment: @grimsan55 In that case I would try changing the `PeriodsModel` to have the property: `Dictionary<string, Period> periods { get; set; }` instead, and see if that works.

Comment: Yes that works, but how do I access lets say the end_date in an easy way ?

Comment: @grimsan55 I think this would work: `model.periods["0"].start_date` because `model.periods` is a `Dictionary` with the keys "0", "1", "2", etc... so you would just access the dictionary as usual.

Comment: Thanks, dunno why I couldn't figure it out.. I'll mark your answer as the correct one since you gave such a detailed explanation even tho Asad gave the correct answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could do it, since the "0" is more of a key and not a property variable:

```
public class PeriodsModel
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("periods")]
    public Dictionary<string, Period> periods { get; set; }
}

public class Period
{
    [JsonProperty("label")]
    public string label { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("start_date")]
    public string start_date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("end_date")]
    public string end_date { get; set; }
}
```